# Trouble setting up SSH keys

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

I'm using rsync to backup our server to another running an rsync daemon on our LAN using the command

> rsync -av /volume1/ Public/ root@192.168.2.20:/shares/Backup/Public/

It's working great except that it requires a manual password entry, so I'd like to automate it with a key pair. Running ssh-keygen I get the below where I hit return 3 times

> ssh-keygen
>       Generating public/private rsa key pair.
>       Enter file in which to save the key (/root/.ssh/id_rsa):
>       Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
>       Enter same passphrase again:
>       Your identification has been saved in /root/.ssh/id_rsa.
>       Your public key has been saved in /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.

ssh-copy-id script isn't on our system, so I used the line below to copy the password file to the backup destination server. I checked and it copied correctly

```
> cat /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh root@192.168.2.20 "cat >> /root/.ssh/authorized_keys"
```

As a test, I ssh to the destination server to ensure there's no longer a password prompt, but I'm still getting one?

```
DiskStation> ssh 192.168.2.20
root@192.168.2.20's password:
```

I'm not strong in unix, so am likely missing something obvious. Suggestions please?

___ Edit ____

Followed up with adding the following settings to sshd_config but still no luck:

```
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
```

Not sure if it matters, but the machine hosting the public key as a WD Sharespace which is a Debian Lenny build.

Comment: What is `PermitRootLogin` set to in your sshd config?

Comment: It's commented out (#PermitRootLogin yes)

Comment: I uncommented it and changed its setting to without-password. Still prompting me for a password, but now it won't accept one. After the third attempt it reports "Permission denied (publickey, password, keyboard-interactive)". I'm wondering if I put the key file in the wrong place? I had to create the .ssh directory and the cat command created the authorized_keys file.

Comment: If you created it from scratch, try setting permission 700 on the .ssh directory.

Comment: Set .ssh permission to 700 and authorized_keys to 600. Still getting password prompt. Also made some additional changes to sshd_config that I'll add to the original post.

Answer (score 1):

The correct procedure for passwordless SSH is as follows:

Begin by executing the ssh-keygen command to generate a key

```
ssh-keygen
```

Once you have the key, then you can copy it to the remote server. Use this command which makes it easier

```
ssh-copy-id user@host
```

The command assumes that you are using port 22 for ssh, if not use, with xxxx being the port number

```
ssh-copy-id "user@host -p xxxx"
```

See [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4830/easiest-way-to-copy-ssh-keys-to-another-machine/4833#4833) for a detailed description of this command

In your case, when you are editing

```
/etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Make sure you modify `PasswordAuthentication` from

```
PasswordAuthentication yes
```

to

```
PasswordAuthentication no
```

then restart sshd with

> service sshd restart

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the key is in your chain. ssh-add ~path/to/private/key otherwise you need to do ssh -i /path/to/key . Then make sure you're using ssh root@whatever. Then make sure the file is written to the remote node properly. Try copying and pasting rather than your cat and pipe. And lastly, try restarting ssh on the remote and perform those steps again (to permit the permitrootlogin to be active).

By the way, the fact that you are trying to avoid entering passwords and then you added a passphrase for the key, makes this entire process pointless.

Comment: I tried your suggestions but am still getting a prompt. I haven't been entering a passphrase lately so edited my original post to reflect that I'm just hitting Return 3x when running ssh-keygen. I restart the both machines but am still getting the prompt. I've been working on this for days and the online tutorials all seem so straightforward I'm befuddled.

Comment: You mentioned you added a setting relating to without-password. Undo that so only the permitrootlogin is present. Make sure you are connecting to the right machine (look in the logs of the auth log of the remote machine. You should see failed auth attempts every time you fail to auth). Then show me your output of 'ssh-add -l'.